# Set initial file extension while saving the file

Tags: file, javafx

I have the following code

```
FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
choose.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text doc(*.txt)", "*.txt"));
File f = choose.showSaveDialog(stage);
```

But after clicking on the Save button in the chooser dialog, created file is in File format, but not in .txt, how to fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got the same problem using JavaFX 2.2.
I'm using following workaround:

```
FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
choose.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text doc(*.txt)", "*.txt"));
File f = choose.showSaveDialog(stage);
if(!f.getName().contains(".")) {
  f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
}
```

Comment: This hack is not complete, the FileChooser checks for the existence of the file and wanrs if it exists internally and all that will be done without the extention, mening it'll check for the wrong file name.

Answer (score 10):

For me it worked best, to

```
FileChooser choose = new FileChooser();
choose.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Text doc(*.txt)", "*.txt"));
choose.setInitialFileName("*.txt");
File file = choose.showSaveDialog(stage);
if (file != null) {
  if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
    // do the operation with the file (i used a builder)
  } else {
    throw new Exception(file.getName() + " has no valid file-extension.");
  }
}
```

The problem of replacing the extension manually like that:

```
if(!f.getName().contains(".")) {
  f = new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + ".txt");
}
```

is, that a file without an extension might not exist, but if the file existed with the extension, it was overwritten without any warning. not expected behaviour.